# How to change the size of Hex bins?

Tags: qgis, hexagon-binning

I am creating a map in QGIS and I am using a hex bin layer. To create this layer I used the MMQGIS plugin and created a grid layer. However, the size of my hexagons that I created are too small, and I was wondering how I can change their size to make them bigger.

Comment: During the creation of these hexbins of course. Which tool did you use? You need to provide us with more information here

Answer (score 1):

You have to choose a greater value for H Spacing or V Spacing.

For hexagons, they are not independent from each other, so you only need to change one of them.

The plugin creates a polygon layer, so not much chance to change the grid afterwards.

You could hack the result by assigning a custom CRS with kilometers as units, then reproject that to metres. I'm not sure if other scaling would work this way too.